# How create parent mapping in FOS_elasticBundle with Elasticsearch 6?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle, elasticsearch-6

Elasticsearch 6 doesn't support parent mapping anymore. Do I have to use "type:join" now? How can I map entity parent in FOS_elasticBundle with Elasticsearch 6?